# Why is being “famous” the most desired profession among kids?

Tags: thought, wandering-mind

Running a small experiment among my 3 children and their friends and their cousins ....

When ever I ask a child what do they want to be when they grow up?  most will answer “rich and famous”.

Rich I can understand, but why famous?

Then again, I am living in Los Angeles, which could explain why ?

But there used to be some times when fame and money didn’t exactly coexist, Example: In the beginning of Hollywood, actors and actresses were well paid, but they were not “rich” by any mega standards.

Plus why wouldn’t a child (generally) think that it be better to be rich and anonymous, rather than famous?

There are more anonymous rich people by far than famous rich people

Regardless to the fact that I live in LA, I am pretty sure that if you ask most kids whether they prefer to be famous than anonymous? , most will answer yes.  (Perhaps the same argument holds true for adults)

Comment: Isn't that just because they are told growing up being rich and famous is a good thing? Also, fame traditionally was a result of power and importance.